# Split a row with data separated by ","

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, string, attribute, split

I need to split a row from a DE. The row contents 4 strings, and I want to see the content in a table. Right now I have some code; but doesn't work:

***Script***

```
%%[
VAR @Productos<br/>

SET @Productos = AttributeValue('Productos') <br/>
SET @item = TreatAsContent('{{item}}')<br/>
SET @sku = TreatAsContent('{{sku}}')<br/>
SET @qty = TreatAsContent('{{qty}}')<br/>
SET @price = TreatAsContent('{{price}}')<br/>
<br/> ]%%
```

***Inside html:***

```
Product: %%=V(@item)=%% <br/>
SKU:  %%=V(@sku)=%% <br/>
Quantity: %%=V(@qty)=%% unidades <br/>
Price:   %%=V(@price)=%% <br/>
```

[image: the row]
[image: the description of the row]

Some images of the error and the code of the "Confirmation Email"

[image: the error in the code]

[The CODE of the EMAIL-CONFIRMATION.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-uWoLNMMby4TWwpwMOw9Yr5uNpK6YiZC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you will likely wanna do this via SSJS instead. There is not really a native way to do this in AMPScript.

Comment: I used ampscript because I did not know how to try to take the information from the "Products" column and show it divided into several columns of a table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Guide Template Language does this effortlessly. No need for SSJS, or awkward AMPscript process loops. The following code:

```js
%%[
var @products
set @products = '[{"item":"Elastic love","sku ":"PUL1288MTL0000M","qty":1,"price":69.00},{"item":"Seashore","sku ":"PEN0576MCLMTL0U","qty":1,"price":59.00}]'
]%%

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>SKU</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

{{.datasource products type=variable source=@products}}
   {{.data}}
      {"target":"@products"}
   {{/data}}

  <tr>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
    <td>{{sku }}</td>
    <td>{{qty}}</td>
    <td>{{price}}</td>
  </tr>

{{/datasource}}

</table>
```

Will produce the following output:

[image: generated table]

All you need to do is change my `set @products` statement to use `set @products = AttributeValue('Productos')`

Comment: Great out of the box usage of GTL! Most people (including myself) forget it even exists and miss places it would be the most elegant solution.

Comment: I have tested your code but it still does not work. I leave an image so you can see the error that it gives me when I include the code inside my HTML. It is for an order confirmation email, and I can not divide it from the "Products" column, divide it by parts and display them as I want. Now it does not work properly because it does not show me the content. And it gives me the error of the image.

I also leave the complete code of the mail. In case something is wrong

Comment: If you copy and paste the code I provided, it should work. I've requested permission to the Google Drive link so I can access your HTML file.

Comment: Thanks Eliot, I give you the access for the html file in Drive. I tried with "copy-paste" the code. But changing "set products = "AttributeValue('Productos')" and doesn't work. When you saw the code, tell me and I made changes.

Comment: @SergioEscobolesOrtiz, there are a couple of issues with your code. Firstly you have wrapped your code block in `<script runat="server">%%[ code ]%% </script>` — don't use both tags and delimiters (just remove the script tags). Secondly, you wrote `set @product = TreatAsContent('Productos')` when it should read `set @products = AttributeValue('Productos')` (the variable name is important).

Comment: Thanks Eliot, I change the code. I wrote this changes in the html code. But I put the declaration of the variables inside the <head> tags and doesn't work. I updated the code in the file of Drive.

Comment: I had a call with Sergio and we figured out the issue. His JSON was malformed (objects in arrays were not separated by commas). I fixed this up using the Replace function and it's working now.

Comment: Everything works thanks to the inestimable help of Eliot. Once again, the community triumphs over SF's external support. Thanks guys.